# How can I require another .rb file in my rhtml file?

Tags: ruby, erb

In my rhtml file, I want to require another ruby file in the same directory. So I tried:

```
<% require_relative 'another.rb' %>
```

but I got this error in my log:

```
(erb):2:in `require_relative': cannot infer basepath (LoadError)
```

Then I tried to use:

```
<% require './another.rb' %>
```

And it gives error saying:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': cannot load such file -- ./views/another.rb (LoadError)
```

Then I tried to see what is the base path by doing:

```
puts File.absolute_path(__FILE__)
```

And it returns:

```
(erb)
```

How can I require another file using `relative path`? I do not want to use absoulute path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the error, the current path is `views` (`app/views`).  If the file you want is in your app's `lib` directory, you could do:

```
<% require_relative '../../lib/another' %>
```

You don't need `.rb`.

This is a fairly bad idea, though; you shouldn't be requiring things from inside views.  If you're trying to access some sort of view-related functionality, you can require it in your controller; all controller actions are accessible to views.  Going this route, it's best to wrap the functionality in a controller method.

You could also put the functionality into a helper; that's what helpers are for.  See `app/helpers/application_helper.rb` for a good starting point, or make one specific to the view.  See [the view helper documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#view-helpers).

Answer (score 0):

A very unhealthy way is to add '.' to the load path

```
$LOAD_PATH << '.'
```

then you can use

```
<% require './another.rb' %>
```

The most usual way I believe that is

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'path', 'to', '..', 'file')
```

If you consider that you are only using a constant and a relative path, I believe it is correct to say that this path is relative.